# jQueryUI themeswitcher not loading images

Tags: jquery-ui, themes

I wanted to play with the themeswitcher a little, so I made a simple page just to see how it worked before messing with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#switcher').themeswitcher();
  $('#calendar').datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="switcher"></div>
  <input type="text" id="calendar"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

But after the page loads, I opened the developer tools panel in chrome and all the images that the script are supposed to load are throwing 403 forbidden errors. Which is weird because he switcher div worked the very first time I tried the page, but I made a typo on the datepicker id, so I reloaded the page after fixing it and then got 403 errors. So I want to get it working again, but it looks like it would be a pain to locally host all the theme resources and change the themeswitcher urls to reflect that; am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I am having this problem too! When I individually try this, this image  (for ex http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/themeGallery/theme_90_ui_light.png) is loading, but when the tool tries to load, it gives this 403 error. Not sure why?

Comment: Same for me.  But when others try to use the same code base it works for them.  I have been doing lots of page refreshes during development and I wonder if they have a traffic restriction.  If so, then this tool is obviously not suited for production.

Comment: [Jquery Theme Switcher - Lost In Action ? - jQuery Forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-theme-switcher-lost-in-action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to hotlink to jQuery properties other than code.jquery.com. http://blog.jquery.com/2010/12/30/hotlinking-to-be-disabled-on-jan-31-2011/

you just need to download the code and images to your own server then modify the code to point to the images you downloaded on your own server.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find where you can download the jQuery theme switcher code but I did come across the following on github https://github.com/harborhoffer/Super-Theme-Switcher

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Tylers answer:

I had similar errors so I downloaded the js from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/, saved it as jquery.themeswitcher.js and replaced all http jquery-ui urls with google apis https urls.

The only changes were in the var switcherpane where each link looks like:

```
<li><a href=
"http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/css/parseTheme.css.php?....">
<img src=
"http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/themeGallery/theme_90_ui_dark.png" alt=
"UI Darkness" title="UI Darkness" /> <span class="themeName">UI
darkness</span></a></li>
```

Which I replaced with:

```
<li><a href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<img src="content/images/theme_90_ui_light.png" alt="UI Lightness" title=
"UI Lightness" /><span class="themeName">UI lightness</span></a></li>
```

If you search through the file there are a few other html images that are referenced further down.

You can find all the images [here](https://github.com/harborhoffer/Super-Theme-Switcher)